# Deleted a partition, now getting 'Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device' message during boot

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, swap

I've recently deleted a partition around `8GB` in size. This partition was located after the main partition, but seems to **not be critical** as I can still boot the OS and run all the applications.

The boot process now takes an extra two-minutes to complete, displaying the following messages:

> `Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device`
>   `/dev/sda4: clean, .../... files .../... blocks`
>   `[ ***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\.....\....\... .device`
>   `Dependencies failed!`

**My question is:**

What was this *second* partition, and how can restore or recreate it?

Comment: Do you see any errors or warnings when the OS starts? If there are no messages at all then maybe your kernel boots with `quiet` and `splash` options. Temporarily edit the GRUB entry and boot without these options. Pay attention especially to messages that stall and the ones directly after.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Added kernel messages

Comment: "Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device" – this makes me think there's a problem with swap partition (but it wouldn't explain missing `ntfs-3g`). Check if your system uses swap, run `swapon`. Next run `swapon -a` and observe. It may complain. The partition you deleted might have been your swap partition.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks, it seems to have been the swap partition, `swapon: cannot find the device for UUID=3fd1..`, attempting to re-create it now. Additionally I've ran the installer for `ntfs-3g`, and it detects my NTFS partitions. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I just encountered that same error message on Debian and a similar boot delay, with a slight variation: I knew that I had just voluntarily deleted my swap partition, and didn't plan to recreate it.

The partition was no longer listed in `/etc/fstab` but the delay persisted. Nothing in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` (Thanks @KamilMaciorowski for the hint).

The key was to figure out that the initial RAM disk is "compiled", and in some case (like this), must be regenerated. Solution: `sudo update-initramfs -u`.

Comment: In my case, /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume contained an old UID reference for the swap. . update-initramfs -u solved the matter. thanks.

Comment: In my case, the above answer hinted me that my recently formated+encrypted (with veracrypt) partition probably failed to mount and all I had to do was `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and then comment-out (prefix with a `#`) the line referring to the partition I encrypted.

Comment: In my case, `find /boot/vmli*` listed 5 available kernels and `uname -r` showed my system uses ``5.13.0-27-generic``.  Beware that `update-initramfs -u` will only update the **latest** kernel, I needed `update-initramfs -u -k all`.

Answer (score 15):

Because of the message

> Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device

I suspect a problem with your swap partition. Check if your system uses swap by running `swapon`. Next run `swapon -a` and observe the output. It may complain with `cannot find the device` message. If so, you will know you should recreate your swap partiton.

**The procedure:**

Refer to a previous question: [How do I restore a swap partition I deleted?](https://askubuntu.com/a/180735/681251)

1. Modify your partition table with `fdisk`, `gdisk`, `gparted` or another equivalent tool. Recreate the partition entry. The partition type should be `0x82 Linux swap`.
2. Set the partition up with `mkswap`.
3. Modify your `/etc/fstab` accordingly (the previous output from `swapon -a` should tell you which entry you need to change in case you're not sure).
4. **Important:** Replace the UUID in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`, with that used in the above step.
5. Run `update-initramfs -u`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the boot message looked like this. The swap partition was deleted.

```
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
/dev/sda4 ... ...

[***] A start job is running for dev-disk-by\...\...\...\.device
...
...
...
```

First, look at the content of your fstab file, 

`cat /etc/fstab`

will return this kind of output

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=8c1977eb-ac90-426b-bc9b-a7fb2ec8d760 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=00fd67-123DE-4b98-aa17-2d4025aed54 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
```

Then you notice , "swap was on /dev/sdax during installation".

Recreate the deleted partition (fdisk or Gparted for instance), then
use this command to find the new uuid of the partition.

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

This outputs:

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 févr. 19 07:18 00151dcd-2bf5-4b98-aa17-8f40ef4cfd86 -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 févr. 19 07:18 6C5A1AC45A1A8B4A -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 févr. 19 07:18 8c1977eb-ac90-426b-bc9b-a7fb2ec8d760 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 févr. 19 07:18 C064106664106188 -> ../../sda1
```

Update your fstab with the correct uuid that were displayed by the last command by copy/pasting the adequate uuid of the swap in the fstab file.
Then reboot, It should correct the problem.